# Docker does not update volume inside container

Tags: docker, synchronization, volumes

Hello I have a docker container running.

I start it with docker-compose and the respective host folder is also mounted as volume

```
  version: '3.3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./build/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php71develop
    container_name: AppPortalH3_dev
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ../AppPortalH3:/var/www/AppPortalH3
      - ../ErnSrc:/var/www/ErnSrc
```

When I modify one file in my editor, outside the container, changes are not been sync inside the container.

I thought that it was a velocity problem but when execute a cat or vim to the file inside the container the file updates inmediatily.

My OS is linux UBUNTU 18.04

Comment: are you sure that it's not a problem with your application that is not refreshing?

Comment: Are those files or directories you mount as volumes?

Comment: Yes, when finally the file updates the apllication works fine

Comment: Have you checked the code that updates the file , make sure that the stream is closed / disposed .

Comment: Hi Soumen the filete are updated by the IDE. Phpstorm concretely

Comment: Are AppPortalH3 and ErnSrc the name of files or are they directories that you are mounting in your container?

Comment: They are directories

Comment: And the files you are modifying are within those directories?

Comment: Yes, is very strange

Comment: Hi, I update the docker engine and make the same behaviour, But I have realized that what is happening is that it takes a long time to update

Answer (score 0):

Can try use a Bind mount like this

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ../AppPortalH3
    target: /var/www/AppPortalH3
  - type: bind
    source: ../ErnSrc
    target: /var/www/ErnSrc
```

Comment: Thanks for your helps, but it's not working. The behavior is the same than before

Comment: Hi, I update the docker engine and make the same behaviour, But I have realized that what is happening is that it takes a long time to update

Comment: Generally it should not take long time , could be a system issue in that case.